# What is the alternative using not CSS selector in Jquery 1.8.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using Jquery to exclude elements from selection I like to use **CSS :not** selector because of faster performance [:not() VS .not()](http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not) , but from Jquery 1.8.0 it is not working anymore:(
Is there some other alternative to use with same or better performance (except **.not()** ) in Jquery? THX!!

This works with Jquery 1.7.2

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AmKBS/)

But NOT with Jquery 1.8.0

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/E7gBM/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul li:not(:first)").hide();
});
```

Comment: You're just doing it wrong, it's supposed to be  `$("ul li:not(:first)")` as there is no `ul li li:first`

Comment: It work's like a charm:) Thank you! Sorry for the typo's in my Fiddles:(

Comment: @DejoDekic, Basically, there was no real question here. Yet you still chose an answer and all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it an actual CSS3 selector. It's much faster:

```
$("li:not(:first-child)").hide();
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E7gBM/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`:gt()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) to exclude the first `li`:

```
$("ul li:gt(0)").hide();
```